# At least 3 words or more but in Arabic [HTML Pattern]

Tags: html, angular

I'm trying to make an input that only accept at least 3 words or more,
found this `([a-zA-Z]+\s){2,}([a-zA-Z]+)` but it only accepts English

I need it like the example below but in Arabic

```
            <input
                required
                pattern="([a-zA-Z]+\s){2,}([a-zA-Z]+)"
                type="text" name="name">
```

Comment: You can use `minlength="3"` option

Comment: @Abhijit is correct if you only want at least 3 characters. To require at least 3 words, you can  use a regex like this `\S+\s+\S+\s+\S+`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the regex you are looking for :
`(?:[\u0600-\u06FF]+ ){2,}[\u0600-\u06FF]+`

For Arabic characters you have to use Unicode, or you can use the letter itself like this : `[ء-ي]`